# How to add underline under text spacing

Tags: html, css

Hi i have some problem about text spacing . Now i need to underline text spacing For example
"`aaaaaaaaa Spaceeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee`" and under this have underline, How to make it .Please help.

Comment: What do you mean underline text spacing? Replace spaces with underlines?

Comment: yes some think like that.

Comment: dont understand ur question.. can you post how does this text should look like ?

Comment: I just left an answer that I tested. Best of luck, ( Happy coding )

Answer (score 3):

If you want to dynamically replace your spaces with underlines.. I recommend this solution.

**For example, your markup:**

```
<div id="myContent">aaaaaaaa Spaaaace</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("myContent").innerHTML
= document.getElementById("myContent").innerHTML.replace(" ", "<u>&nbsp;</u>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you want to underline spaces, this is how you could do it.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szkha3ov/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<div>Some text <pre><u>        </u></pre></div>
```

#### CSS:

```
pre, div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```